# App can't be tested because of conflit with django.contrib.messages

Tags: python, django, django-testing

In my django project, I'm having trouble testing my homemade app named "messages". If I write a single test in `messages/tests.py` and try to run it with `python manage.py test messages`, it will perform 74 tests from, I guess, the `django.contrib.messages` library.

How can I run my local app tests instead of the library one without renaming it? All other tests for my apps with other names run fine.

Comment: Maybe a more absolute call will help? i.e. `manage.py test myproject.messages?`

Comment: Just tried, but the command is waiting for an app name since I got "App with label myproject could not be found" error message.

Comment: Got another idea, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your application appears in your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS *before* django.contrib.messages does.